# Set audience on specific node in SharePoint quick launch with powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm using a script for setting an audience group for a navigation node in SharePoint. When I set the group It's no problem, or it sets the group but the settings is never pushed through. But If I edit the node in the GUI and just press OK (on both the node settings and navigation settings) the changes goes through.

Script:

```
$FindString = "Custom link"

Get-SPSite "http://dev:18792/sites/devsite/" | Get-SPWeb -Limit ALL | ForEach-Object {
$web = $_
  $_.Navigation.QuickLaunch | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Children | ForEach-Object {
        if($_.title -eq $FindString){
            $node = $_
            $node.Properties["Audience"] = "Custom group"
            $node.Update()

        }
    }
  }
$web.Update()
}
```

Am I using the Updates in the wrong place?

EDIT: "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature **is activated** on the site collection.

Comment: I'm not trying to nitpick but I think it would be a good idea to avoid putting everything on the same line. In essence, your code is a one-liner.
It's easier to read and debug if you put your results in variables and then loop through them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding ;;;; before the group name.

```
  $node.Properties["Audience"] = ";;;;Custom group"
```

Comment: Helped me out in case of adding more than one group